# Tracking a twitter hashtag

Tags: software-development, twitter

I need to do a research with specific boundaries about the tweets I want to analyze.

Requirements are:

- Be able to track one specific hashtag (The hashtag I want to track is: #2popesaints).
- Be able to limit by time/date (I'm interested in the date range April 23rd 2014 and April 28th 2014).
- Be able to limit by geolocation data (I need the tweets to be geolocalized in Rome.)
- Free or at least a fully functional trial available.

I've checked Google all around for a web-app that let me do something like that, but all the solution that I found missed something.

For example, I tried http://topsy.com/, that lets me refine by hashtag and date, but gives me only the list of all the tweets, without telling me any data about them, and I cannot filter them by geolocation.

I found [this article](http://schoolofdata.org/harvesting-and-analyzing-tweets/) but the tools mentioned need to be paid. Nothing wrong with it, but I'm really tight on budget and I can spend a bit of money only when I'm 100% sure of the outcome.

With http://www.hashtracking.com I made the free search and I got limited data, but once again I'm not really sure that I could refine the search as much as I need, if I go for the paid service.

http://www.talkwalker.com/en/home/ doesn't allow me to do some free tests without signing up, so it's like all the above.

Does anyone know of any web-app that can meet those requirements? Alternatively does anyone know of a way to do that with any of the above mentioned web-apps? I don't having to pay for the functionality however I'm on a tight budget and want to be sure it will work before I pay.

Comment: Since the rise of online services, I think that an online website that does a service is a matter of fact a software. So, if I am asking a recomendation for a software that does a service I need, why the question has been put on hold?

Comment: yeah I think I may have been a bit over-zealous in my close voting of this. Usually I at least comment; sorry for the poor welcome. I've voted to reopen and edited it to closer match our requirements. Web-apps are on-topic but services are off-topic; the problem is of course that there is quite a gradual transition between those two. I did have a couple more things I wanted to edit in but couldn't without further information from you; Would you also be interested in: a desktop app? (if so what OS?) How about a API/programming library?

Comment: Sorry, but I still think this is of-topic. Services != webapps.

Answer (score 1):

I just implemented the geolocation feature in my software [TweetsToRSS Server](http://www.vsubhash.com/article.asp?id=128&info=Subhash_TweetsToRSS_RelayServer) thanks to this post.

TweetsToRSS Server is a localhost RSS/HTML server for Twitter.

To track a hashtag, create an RSS feed and use it in Thunderbird/Seamonkey or any RSS feed reader application or browser extension. Bamboo is a good one. Limit results to a location specified by "&latitude=" and "&longitude=" parameters in the URL. Date limitations can be done using the Twitter search format with "since:" and "until" options.

This is a Java software. You need J2SE installed.

It can be hosted on a LAN computer too and shared in a network.

It is free and has no ads.

I will add the geolocation feature to the Android version soon.
[image: TweetsToRSS results in Seamonkey browser]