# Easy Java server to create and store forms?

Tags: web-apps, java

I would like to have an easy-to-learn Java web server, with which I can create a web application to create/store/fill out online forms. I don't want to have any PHP and I'm very good at Java, that's why I would prefer this method. I already have a few solutions in my mind, but would be interested in other people's ideas.

What I also need is an API which is able to process registration from different social networks: Facebook, Google+, etc.

Also, I would the store the user created forms in an SQL database.

Any ideas?

Comment: Shouldn’t the API question be posted in a separate question post, or does the same software have to include this API? -- Or is it that you don’t need the actual web server software, but a CMS that allows you to build the web site/app (with the forms and the registration API)?

Comment: To be honest, I'm not a web development expert. I'm asking in one question, because I want them to easily operate with each other.
The solution I have in my mind is to use Struts2 for the framework, as for the social netwok API I'm still doing my research.

Comment: I found Apache Shindig but unfortunately it's sent to retirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Nano HTTP](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd) server, which is written entirely in Java. I used it for my [Twitter server app](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/7090/tracking-a-twitter-hashtag/26634#26634) with the Twitter4J library. There is also a Facebook4j library that you can use.